# How do I print what I see on the screen/debugger with as few lines of code as possible?

Tags: c++, debugging, printing, screen

hello I have a c++ program that my class group for C++ are working on. It is due in 7 minutes. How do I print what I see on the screen/debugger with as few lines of code as possible?

Comment: Take a screenshot, paste it into an image editing program, and hit print. 0 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't specified otherwise, I'll assume you intend this to run on the one true operating system (MS-DOS). With it, the code can be as simple as:

```
.model tiny, C

main proc
    div al
    ret
main endp
    end main
```

Explanation: division by zero causes an exception. When IBM designed the IBM PC BIOS, they hooked that interrupt to the print-screen routine (even though Intel had already said that the interrupt was reserved). Therefore, dividing by 0 will print the current screen contents. Of course, you could just use `int 5` instead of `div al`, but what would be the fun in that?

Answer (score 0):

Print from screen/debugger?  You mean print from code?

```
#include<stdio.h>

...

printf("Hello World.\n");
```